# Error in C preprocessor concatenation with variable and function (dynamically indexing in a for loop)

Tags: c, for-loop, concatenation, token, c-preprocessor

I ran this code in [this compiler](https://repl.it/languages/c)

```
#define CCc(n) CC_##n
#define CC(n) CCc(n)
#define CC_1 (1,2)
#define CC_2 (3,4)
#define CALL_FUNCTION(xy) Coord(xy)
#define YES 1
#define NO 0
int Coord(x, y){
    if (x < 0.5 && y < 1.5){
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}


int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
        CALL_FUNCTION(CC(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and got this error:

> > error: use of undeclared identifier 'CC_i'

Why does this error occur? And what is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: `CC(i)` will be replaced by `CC_i`, which is undeclared. The `define` does not use the value of `i`, but the character `i`.

Comment: is it possible to use value of `i` rather than char `i`?

Comment: No, because `i` is getting a value at run-time, not compile-time. The pre-processor can only work with compile-time pre-processor tokens, not variable values. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The names `__YES`, `__NO` and `_CC` are illegal in C and C++, since all names starting with an underscore + uppercase letter, or with two underscores, are reserved for the platform.

Comment: @Lundin there are around 100 predefined positions being supposed to be imported into `Coord` function. I reckon I should start using an array! yes?

Comment: @GntS Yeah sounds like, so why do it at compile time? I posted a compile-time example as an answer, but maybe you should simply do this with arrays in run-time instead.

Comment: @Lundin, I was just curious to implement my code by using macros since I have employed arrays many times so far!!! Just to learn a new way! Thank you for your compile-time example. it was Informative for me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do run-time/variable evaluations in the pre-processor. It requires compile-time pre-processor tokens. So rather than trying to define a number of `#define` based on run-time values, you should gather all compile-time constants in one place.

A common way to do so is "X macros". In your case it might look like this:

```
#define CC_LIST \
/*  n  x  y  */ \
  X(1, 1, 2)    \
  X(2, 3, 4)    \

int main()
{
    #define X(n,x,y) (void) Coord(x, y);
      CC_LIST
    #undef X

    return 0;
}
```

This expands to `(void) Coord(1,2); (void) Coord(3,4);`, so it is a compile-time loop unrolling of sorts.

Alternatively, if you insist on having the "CC_N" macros because they are also needed for other purposes, you can do this:

```
#define CC_LIST \
/*  n  */       \
  X(1)          \
  X(2)          \

#define CC(n) CC_##n
#define CC_1 1,2
#define CC_2 3,4

#define CALL_FUNCTION(...) (void) Coord(__VA_ARGS__);


int main()
{
  #define X(n) CALL_FUNCTION(CC(n))
    CC_LIST
  #undef X

  return 0;
}
```

As you can tell, macro tricks like "X macros" are not easy to read and should be regarded as the last resort. Only use them when proper program re-design is not possible, for example during maintenance of existing code.